# Throwing required primary key error while trying to define a BaseModel in django_cassandra_engine with abstract=True

Tags: django-models, cassandra

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import models as cassandra_models


class BaseCassandraMixin(cassandra_models.Model):
    meta = columns.Text()
    is_active = columns.Boolean(index=True)
    created_at = columns.DateTime()
    updated_at = columns.DateTime()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I am trying to define a BaseMixin. Getting error on primary key is not defined , even after defining class to be abstract.

```
class BaseCassandraMixin(cassandra_models.Model):
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/models.py", line 901, in __new__
    raise ModelDefinitionException("At least 1 primary key is required.")
cassandra.cqlengine.models.ModelDefinitionException: At least 1 primary key is required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, one of the columns needs to be defined as the primary key.

For example:

```
meta = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
```

Cheers!

Comment: but why its necessary for an abstract model.